# Azure Logic Apps FTP Trigger Failure

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-logic-apps

I am using [Azure's Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/) for data management of stock data. 
Specifically, I set up an [FTP trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp#connector-specific-details) that checks for updates on an FTP server every 5 minutes and downloads the new files to my cloud Blob if there are any.

My main problem arises from the fact that my provider seems to limit the amount of active connections to the FTP server to 1 per customer. As a consequence, around 6 pm CET when most European Stock markets' data gets available for that day, my trigger detects up to 6 files out of which roughly half will fail.

Now I've tried playing around with the [retry-policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling) which is limited to (and by default) 4 x . At this point I am considering running two triggers in parallel in 2.5 minute interval and filtering based on the file name (e.g. A-M in Logic App1 & N-Z in Logic App 2), but there must be a more elegant solution?

Comment: I have a similar issue. My logic app trigger monitors a BLOB container, and when a file hits, it pushes it to an FTPS site. If 30 files hit at once, I get intermittent failures as the FTPS host only allows 10 concurrent connections. Their support staff told me that the process is trying to open 30 connections at the same time, instead of opening 1 connection, and sending all 30 under the same connection. It would also work if the process were serial, meaning get 1 file, open connection, send file, close connection, and then do remaining 29. Any ideas? Looking like this will now work. :-(

Comment: Hi Daniel. How about a Http triggered Azure function as a solution to your problem? You could pass a virtually unlimited number of file names from your logic app to the azure function. 
The Azure function will allow you to take control of each connection and its retry-policy. Of course, this would mean more work from your side, but it might be a solution to your problem.

Comment: I ended up creating a continual Web Job using the SSH.net NuGet package. It actually gives me better error handling. I appreciate the advice, though, It's a great idea.